# How to align the div tag using css and html

Tags: html, css

I want to aligh the div tags as mentioned in the link . I need to fit the whole div in a  wrapper and it should be center of the page
       div1
       div2
       div3
       div4
       div5
       div6
[DIV outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuCyP.png)

Comment: First Try yourself....Give Us some code which have error..
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp"/>

OR
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp"/>

Comment: Please provide code from your project.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the wrapper div element. Define it with a fixed width of 1000px or something that you like. To make the wrapper align center, just set the left and right margins of it to `auto`.

For the first free space inside that wrapper, you could set a `padding-top` to the wrapper element or a `margin-top` to the `DIV1` element.

For the `DIV3`, `DIV4`, `DIV5`, you could enlcose them in another div. And set these three divs to `float` left. Make sure you set the width to these three divs. After these three divs, you need to use `clear` attribute so that the floats will be cleared.
This is one way, there is some other way too achieve the same.

Anyway, I give you some ideas. Now try it and show us your code. We will give you more suggestions upon seeing the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from the image you provided, the html will be like:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div>DIV1</div>
<div>DIV2</div>
<div class='inlineDivs'>DIV3</div>
<div class='inlineDivs'>DIV4</div>
<div class='inlineDivs'>DIV5</div>
<div>DIV6</div>
</div>
```

and required css will be:

> .inlineDivs {
>    display: inline;
>    width: 33.3%;
>    text-align: center;
>   }
>   .wrapper {
>    width: 800px;
>   }

Adjust the width as required.